# Java 8 ParallelStream Inside Web Application Container

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a more general knowledge type question than a code issue.

I can use the following code to create a parallel stream:

```
// create List, assign to variable myList
Stream<String> stream = myList.parallelStream();
```

However, in the world of web applications, most guidance says to let the container (JBoss, Weblogic, etc) manage threads and thread pools for you. So that leads to my question: is it considered poor practice to use `parallelStream()` inside a web application?

Jason

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is *depends*: first of all, you are talking about **different** levels of abstraction. If is a different thing to create your own thread in your code; and have that do something; or to know that your container is providing thread pools and such concepts.

If your Web App container program used explicit threading/parallelism *before* Java8 was coming along (like doing native work using Javas' Thread or ExecutorService class) ... then of course you could go forward and change that code to use parallel streams. You would not be doing much else than before; just using somehow improved abstraction layers.

On the other hand: if you wrote your programs really in a way that the container infrastructure was responsible for all "threading" aspects; then  you probably stay with that pattern.